# How to parse a XML Documents Into a NSMutable Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

I have a response from web service in the following format,which gives me Employee's personal information, what is the best way to parse and store these contact in a mutable array.

```
<S_CONTACT>
              <CONTACT_FNAME>jim</CONTACT_FNAME>
              <CONTACT_LNAME>dsouza</CONTACT_LNAME>
              <CONTACT_ID>111</CONTACT_ID>
              <ORGID>111</ORGID>
           </S_CONTACT>

 <S_CONTACT>
             <CONTACT_FNAME>peter</CONTACT_FNAME>
              <CONTACT_LNAME>dsouza</CONTACT_LNAME>
              <CONTACT_ID>111</CONTACT_ID>
              <ORGID>222</ORGID>
           </S_CONTACT>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you to use [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html)

Also suggest you to read [XML Tutorial for iOS by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Answer (score 0):

I always used NSXML and I've never had any problems.
My advice is to use NSXML. There are a lot of tutorials on the net.
Like [this](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser).
Following the tutorial you will understand how to put your data into an `NSMutableArray`